# A filtered list in React flashes for a split second the whole list while clicking on an item

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Hi I'm quite new to React and I am making a list of dishes which you can upvote. The dishes are fetched from Firebase and displayed as a list with a dropdown filter so that you can filter on a food category.

Filtering works fine and upvoting works as well when the app loads for the first time, however when the list is filtered and you click on the upvote button the whole list with all categories flashes for a split second before it updates the number of votes and displaying the filtered list again. How can I fix this?

The code looks like this:

App:

```
function App() {
  const [dishes, setDishes] = useState([]);
  const [category, setCategory] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    // This code fires when the app loads

    let collection = firebase.firestore().collection("dishes");

    if ((category === "All") | (category.length === 0)) {
      collection = collection;
    } else {
      collection = collection.where("category", "==", category);
    }


    collection.onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
      const newData = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
        id: doc.id,
        ...doc.data(),
      }));
      setDishes(newData);
    });
  }, [category]);

  return (
    <div className="justify-center sm:mx-44 mt-10 ">
      <h1 className="text-4xl mt-10 mx-4 ">Snibble</h1>
      <h5 className=" mx-4 mb-10">Rate your favorite snibble dish!</h5>

      <SearchBar
        dishes={dishes}
        setCategory={setCategory}
      />


      {dishes.map((dish) => (
        <Dish dish={dish} key={dish.id} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The Dish component has the following functionality and is attached to the upvote button with an onnClick:

```
function handleVote() {
    const voteRef = firebase.firestore().collection("dishes").doc(dish.id);
    voteRef.get().then((doc) => {
      if (doc.exists) {
        //console.log(doc.data().dish);
        const previousVotes = doc.data().stars;
        const newVote = previousVotes + 1;
        voteRef.update({ stars: newVote });
      }
    });
  }
```

The Searchbar component looks like this:

```
  <Select
        //defaultValue={categoriesList(dishes)[0]}
        placeholder="Select Category"
        onChange={(e) => setCategory(e.value)}
        //value={'All'}
        options={categories}/>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to [`return collection.onSnapshot(...)`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference#returns-=-void) from [`useEffect()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#cleaning-up-an-effect) to unsubscribe from the current collection's changes when `category` changes.

What you're seeing now is `onSnapshot` being called for both the unfiltered and filtered collection simultaneously when `voteRef.update()` commits to firebase.

Answer (score 0):

`collection.onSnapshot` is a listener that fires every time the collection is updated. When your `handleVote` function is called, the `collection.onSnapshot` listener fires too. You should use the `collection.get` function in your `useEffect` instead, so that it only happens when your `useEffect` fires.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    // This code fires when the app loads

    let collection = firebase.firestore().collection("dishes");

    if ((category === "All") | (category.length === 0)) {
      collection = collection;
    } else {
      collection = collection.where("category", "==", category);
    }


    collection.get().then((snapshot) => {
      const newData = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
        id: doc.id,
        ...doc.data(),
      }));
      setDishes(newData);
    });
  }, [category]);
```

Comment: Except that the `voteRef.update()` will now no longer cause the respective update to be returned from the observed collection. _"When your handleVote function is called, the collection.onSnapshot listener fires too."_ That is the intended behavior. What _isn't_ intended is that when `category` changes, the code in the question does not correctly unsubscribe from the previous collection's snapshots.